# Wrong output for math.log

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, precision, logarithm

I am trying to compute the nearest 2^n to a very large number(<=10^19)

I have tried to use math.log(number,2). But that is giving wrong results for very big numbers. How should I do this without using other libraries?

```
a = 9843649374639837463  # a is any num between 1 and 10^9
number = int(math.log(a,2))
```

Comment: please provide a simple code demo

Comment: maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: Take a look at "int.bit_length()"

Comment: What is the smallest `a`?

Answer (score 7):

The large integer input is being converted to a float with limited precision, so s[ome input precision is being lost](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).  Also, [*math.log2()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.log2) can be more accurate than *math.log()* because it is fine-tuned for base two.

There is an *int* method that will be dead-on accurate, [*bit_length()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_length):

```
>>> a = 9843649374639837463
>>> a.bit_length()
64
>>> bin(a)
'0b1000100010011011101010101111001111001100111001110101000100010111'
```

Note, the floating point log is pretty close but not exact:

```
>>> a = 9843649374639837463
>>> 2.0 ** math.log2(a)
9.843649374639845e+18
>>> abs(a - 2.0 ** math.log2(a))
8192.0
```